# Replace character based on range of coordinates

Tags: linux, text-processing

Hi I have a text file with thousands of lines which looks like this:

```
NNNNN
NNNNN
NNNNN
NNNNN
```

I would like to substitute based on their location coordinate all the letters within a specific range to another letter, let's say I want to replace all the N letters from range position 10 to position 13 to letter P, the output will be :

```
NNNNN
NNNNP
PPPNN
NNNNN
```

Any suggestion about the command I could use?

Comment: Just to remove extra thinking by future readers, you're counting positions in overall sequence, not by column number.

Comment: Do all the columns have same width? PS. Feels like XY problem to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=10
end=13
first=$(head -n 1 file)
width=${#first}
text=$(paste -sd "" file)
mod="${text:0:start-1}$(tr N P <<<"${text:start:end-start+1}")${text:end}"
grep -Eo ".{1,$width}" <<<"$mod"
```

```
NNNNN
NNNNP
PPPNN
NNNNN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr -d '\n' <file | perl -pe 'substr($_, 9, 4, "P"x4)' | fold -w 5
NNNNN
NNNNP
PPPNN
NNNNN
```

This first removes all newlines from the data in the input file, then uses `substr()` in Perl to replace the text at offset 9 of length 4 with upper-case `P`.  The `fold` utility is then used to fold the lines at five characters.  There is no newline at the end of the output.