# Why does my script create an extra character?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I know this isn't a good thing to do and/or a good solution but I was just messing around trying to answer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/529569/237982) question and I came across the following problem.

The goal is to read the input file character by character and if the character is within the specified range, replace it.

Input:

```
NNNNN
NNNNN
NNNNN
NNNNN
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

input=~/tmp/in
declare -i count=0
low=$1
high=$2
new_char=$3

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
    while IFS= read -rn1 char; do
        if ((count>=low)) && ((count<=high)); then
            printf '%s' "$new_char"
        else
            printf '%s' "$char"
        fi
        ((count++))
    done <<<"$(printf '%s' "$line")"
    echo
done <"$input"
```

Desired output (when run as: `./script.sh 10 13 P`):

```
NNNNN
NNNNP
PPPNN
NNNNN
```

Actual output:

```
$ ./script.sh 10 13 P
NNNNN
NNNNPP
PPNNN
NNNNN
```

I'm not sure why it's seemingly creating a new character out of thin air on the 2nd line and not replacing the 13th character on the 3rd line.  I've tried moving the `((count++))` statement to the beginning of the second while loop, I've tried starting at `count=1`, I've tried seemingly every combination of `((++count))` || `count=$((count+1))` || `((count+1))`.  With varying results but all seem to add an extra character on the second line.

I've double checked that the input file has no trailing whitespace on any of the lines.

Comment: `count` must be 1 at the beginning or put `((count++))` at the beginning of the inner loop. Then if you use `done < <(printf '%s' "$line")` instead of `done <<<"$(printf '%s' "$line")"`, it works as intended. I don't know why yet...

Comment: I think `<<<"string"` creates a temp file in the background, and bash is not stripping the trailing newline like command substitution does.

Comment: If you run with `set -x`, you will see a `printf %s ''` at the end of every line except for on the line that becomes too long.  This possibly means that your inner `read` returns an empty string at the end of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here Strings seem to produce a newline at the end:

You can try and see the difference:

```
cat <<<"test"
cat <(printf '%s' "test")
```

So, you should use  `< <(printf '%s' "$line")` instead of `<<<"$(printf '%s' "$line")"`.

Comment: If here-strings didn't have a newline at the end then they wouldn't be valid text files per POSIX and so YMMV with running any POSIX text-manipulation tools on the result just like running them on `< <(printf '%s' "$line")`.

Answer (score 3):

I would write:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do
        char=${line:i:1}
        ((count++))
        ((low <= count && count <= high)) && char=$new_char
        printf '%s' "$char"
    done
    echo
done <"$input"
```